# res->getString() crashes the application

Tags: mysql, winapi, visual-c++, mysql-connector

**HOW IT SHOULD WORK**: User clicks on a listbox with multitude of IDs. Then, the edit controls are filed with the data from the specified ID (row).

**HOW IT WORKS**: It crashes at res->getString

```
case LBN_SELCHANGE:
{
    string str;
    int index = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_lbList), LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
    string sint = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(index);
    string smt="SELECT client, telnr, atnrem, papatn, gedapr 
                                   FROM tremreg WHERE id = ";
    string query = smt + sint;
    res = stmt->executeQuery(query.c_str());
    //starts crashing here
    str = res->getString("client");
    SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_eClient, str.c_str());

    str = res->getString("telnr");
    SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_eTelNr, str.c_str());

    str = res->getString("antrem");
    SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_eRemAtn, str.c_str());

    str = res->getString("paprem");
    SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_ePapAtn, str.c_str());

    str = res->getString("gedapr");
    SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_eGedApr, str.c_str());

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
}
break;
```

**CRASH INFO**:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x753C812F in Registracija.exe: 
Microsoft C++ exception:sql::InvalidArgumentException at memory location 0x0018F7AC.
```

Digging around google I found somebody mentioning that VARCHAR type values should be fetched with `getBlob`. That did not help at all though, and crashed just the same. getInt works however, and is used in other parts of the program.

**QUESTION**: What steps should I take to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

does the same query run properly if you do it in the database directly? Also, are all the returned fields really Strings? And is it valid to call them by name, rather than by the sequence number? I.e. getString(1), etc.

Comment: Yes, they do run in the database directly. All the returned fields are `VARCHAR` in the database, and I need my program to fetch `VARCHAR` and stuff them up in their respective edit controls. Neither `getString` or `getBlob` work so far. Calling them by sequence number doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it also crash if you call the elements in the resultset by their sequence number? do you really have anything returned by that resultset, i.e. do you get connected to the database? How do you create your stmt object? last but not least, should your query have a semicolon at the end?

Comment: Yes, it does crash even if I call the elements by their sequence number. Yes, I get connected to that database, since it fetches the ID (int) successfully in another part of the program. `stmt = con->createStatement();` is created in `WinMain`, right before creating the dialog. And my queries work, so it's not a semicolon. It's the string retrieval part that blows. **Trying to replicate it in a console program gives me an overrun buffer error.**

Comment: Interesting. Looks like the string is too big? Perhaps you should try to check the warnings (with `stmt->getWarnings`)

Comment: Further testing gives me some suspicion that it has something to do with encoding. The DB uses UTF-8. I'm using... uhh... strings... Because the fields that don't crash on `getstring` are shown with lots of strange characters.

Comment: try to create table with latin encoding and see if you still get an error?

Comment: It does not help at all.

Comment: then you'll at least check your hypothesis that you get an issue because of the encoding